# Submenu Closing Function Semi-working, Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im having an issue dealing with this function bug. What im trying to do is when a user clicks anywhere outside of the box, the box should close. Its working just for a few clicks, then it stops. At first the console has no errors, but when I do my first click, it reads cannot read property style of null. My confusion is that it works for a few clicks, then it stops. Any tips please!

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
  let box = document.querySelector(".sub-menu.open");
  if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box) {
    box.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```
<ul class="nav__links">
            <div class="desktop__nav">
              <li class="parent">
                <a href="#">Product</a>

                <img
                  class="menu-arrow"
                  src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg"
                  alt="arrow"
                />
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li>Overview</li>
                  <li>Pricing</li>
                  <li>Marketplace</li>
                  <li>Features</li>
                  <li>Integrations</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="parent">
                <a href="#">Company</a>
                <img
                  class="menu-arrow"
                  src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg"
                  alt="arrow"
                />
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li>About</li>
                  <li>Team</li>
                  <li>Blog</li>
                  <li>Careers</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="parent">
                <a href="#">Connect</a>
                <img
                  class="menu-arrow"
                  src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg"
                  alt="arrow"
                />
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li>Contact</li>
                  <li>Newsletter</li>
                  <li>LinkedIn</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </div>
```

```
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.open {
  @include mobile {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: $footer-text;
    width: 60vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: $darkblue-headingtext;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 6px auto;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The code works but then it stops after a few clicks

Comment: Your console is telling you "There is no such element: `.sub-menu.open`". Use your devtools to find out what is happening... shouldnt be too hard., You could post a running example that is able to reproduce the problem if you're not able to figure out what goes wwrong

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

No JS required! Get that pesky language out of here and replace it with CSS, where we can use tabindex="0" on the dropdown parent element to allow us to use CSS :focus! With that, we can easily and reliably change styling based off the downtown parent focussed state, either

```
opacity: 0; pointer-events: none;
```

or

```
opacity: 1; pointer-events: all;
```

I hope this is what you were looking for and helped! Please comment if you'd like further explanation or need this in JS.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.dropdownbutton {
  padding: 20px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: lightgray 0 12px 40px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.dropdownbutton:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  background: lightgray;
}

.dropdownbutton span {
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.dropdownparent:hover button span {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dropdownparent {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.dropdowncontentparent {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: -13px;
  top: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.dropdowncontentchild {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0 12px 22px 2px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055) 0 12px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: max-content;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background: var(--nav);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdowncontentchild:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 12px 22px 2px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) 0 12px 12px;
}

.dropdowncontentchild a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: black;
}

.dropdowncontentchild a:hover {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.dropdownparent:focus .dropdowncontentparent {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  top: 30px;
}

.dropdownparent:focus .dropdownbutton {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdownparent" tabindex="0">
  <a class="dropdownbutton">Dropdown Button</a>
  <div class="dropdowncontentparent">
    <div class="dropdowncontentchild">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Carson! Just saw this comment!